# Jquery Ajax Post Issue

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to send some information to my php page via an ajax call. However I am getting an issue that a } missing after property list. Below is my code:

```
function article(Article){  
var surl =  "http://www.webapp-testing.com/includes/article_desc.php";
var id = 1;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: surl,
    data: '"Article="+Article';
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache : false,
    jsonp : "onJSONPLoad",
    jsonpCallback: "articlecallback",
    crossDomain: "true",
    success: function(response) {
       alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {           
       alert('Unknown error ' + status);
    }       
});     
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is `Article` here? Is it a number? Also I once had the same problem, and I was messing up with `"` and `'` signs. I recommend that you use a consistent scheme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the `;` after your `data` attribute to a `,`.

`data: '"Article="+Article',`

Comment: I agree, but i think those single quotes are also a problem

Answer (score 0):

This string should end with `,`:

```
data: '"Article="+Article';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon after the "data" element. It should be a comma.

Answer (score 0):

replace the the semicolon on line `data: '"Article="+Article';` with `,`